# hibernate EventListener and stackoverflow error

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently came across a situation where I have to do some actions when object is deleted through Hibernate session.

I wan't to remove unidirectionl relashonship before an entity is deleted, but the following code results in a stackoverflow exception.

```
@Component("emsPreListener")
public class IntegrationEntityDeleteListener implements PreDeleteEventListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2245534615822054792L;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean onPreDelete(PreDeleteEvent event) {

        System.out.println("PRE-DELETE");

        Session session = event.getSession();

        if (event.getEntity() instanceof Project) {
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try
            {
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();

                Project project = (Project) event.getEntity();

                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectPoll.class);
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("project", project));
                List<ProjectPoll> polls = criteria.list();
                if(polls != null) {
                    for(ProjectPoll projectPoll : polls) {
                        session.delete(projectPoll);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(transaction != null) transaction.commit();
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

This it the only entity with the relashonship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_poll")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "poll_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class ProjectPoll extends Poll {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2230614967405436988L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

Tnx

Comment: How many ProjectPoll records are present per project?

Comment: Lot of ProjectPoll could be present per Project.

Answer (score 0):

You annotated bidirectional relation ProjectPoll.project with cascade=CascadeType.ALL. Removing a projectPoll will remove also a parent (project). This in turn will trigger onPreDelete() once more. Try to remove cascade attribute on bidirectional relation.

Comment: The relation between entities is no bidirectional. Architecture was designed to be as modular as possible and Project is in the core module and cannot be modified. Actually I solve the mentioned problem using a custom implementation of ProjectService, but I'm still interested to know why Listener doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand aright one Project may be assigned to many ProjectPolls. In this case removing projectPoll in onPreDelete() will also trigger removing Project through you cascade definition! In my undestanding this will call your behavior in the if()-clauses on the same project-object! As result you get stackoverflow error.

Comment: As I said before, removing cascade=CascadeType.ALL will probably help you. In my undestanding explicitelly defining Delete cascade is a redundance because project instance is already removed.

What you need is just to set the reference to NULL. Try projectPoll.setProject(null) instead of session.delete(projectPoll);